# Variable with reg expression is not recognized in js

Tags: javascript, regex, variables, undefined

I am trying to generate a template using slush, my code repo is here:
https://github.com/NaveenDK/slush-template-generator/blob/master/templates/react-native-app/MediaButtons.js

Even though the template files run fine on its own, when I try to generate using slush with the following lines in the MediaButtons.js file

```
 let match = /\.(\w+)$/.exec(filename);
    let type = match ? `image/${match[1]}` : `image`;
```

I get an error which says that 'match' is not defined, when I scaffold it with slush and when it is in the templates folder . 
My guess is that the reg expression is not interpreted properly

Thanks for any help!
Naveen

Comment: So do you say that it throws error?

Comment: yes the error is only shown when it is in the templates folder of the slush scaffold

Comment: Its weird. In this case, error like that should occur only if variable `match` is not declared..

Comment: I have tried this too   var re = new RegExp('\.(\w+)$');
              let match = re.exec(filename);
 Still the same error (match is not defined)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you generate with Slush, your code is changed (minimized or whatever you are asking it to do) but the literal templates are not. So at runtime the variable `match` is not declared anymore but still you access it while evaluating `type`'s literal value. And an error is raised.

When you do not generate with Slush, your code is unchanged and works.

To avoid this issue, change to this:

```
let match = /\.(\w+)$/.exec(filename);
let type = match ? 'image/'+match[1] : 'image';
```